# Locally finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

**Definition:** A field is locally finite if every its finitely generated subfield is finite.

*Show that a field $K$ is locally finite iff it is embeddable to the algebraic closure of $F_p$, for some prime p.*

---

- For the "only if" part:

  Assume $K$ is locally finite. Then I'm able to write $K$ as a union of its nested subfields $K_n$ such that $K_n$ is generated by n elements of $K$. For example,

  $K_1$=<1>

  $K_2$=<1, $a_1$> where  $a_1$$\notin$$K_1$

  $K_3$=<1, $a_1$, $a_2$>   where $a_2$$\notin$$K_2$

  .

  .

  $K_{n+1}$=<1, $a_1$,.., $a_n$>   where $a_n$$\notin$$K_n$

  Since $K_n$ is embeddable to the algebraic closure of $F_p$, $K$ is embeddable as well.

Is it ok for 'only if' part??

- In "if" part:

  Assume $K$ is embeddable to the algebraic closure of $F_p$. Then I think that I may write a sequence ($n_i$: i$\in$$N$) such that $n_i$ divides $n_{i+1}$ for all i. And I can use this sequence to represent the subfields $F_{p^{n_i}}$ of  $K$...

  Well, I'm not sure for the 'if' part. Is there any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but
if $K$ is locally finite then it is algebraic over its own prime subfield $F \subset K$, which is finite thus K is embeddable in $\overline{F}$..

Comment: Also $\overline{F}$ is algebraic but not finite. K doesn't need to be finite.

Comment: $F$ is prime, so $F=F_p$ for some $p$. So we have embedding $K \subset \overline{F_p}$. 
I agree that $K$ is not finite but that was not the question you asked. $\overline{F_p}$ is locally finite but not finite

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you at first. I think you've said that K is finite. Well, you say that K is algebraic extension of prime field, because of this it's embeddable. Yeah, it makes sense now for me.

Comment: I think there is some mistakes in 'only if' part. Because you assume the $\{K_n\}_{n\geq{1}}$ can enumerate every element in $K$. However your method is only suit for countable field $K$.

Comment: Ok, but in question we mention of algebraic closure of $F_p$ and it's countable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another criterion you may find helpful - the following are equivalent:

1) $K$ is locally finite
2) $K$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ for some prime $p$
3) $K$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime $p$

Personally, I think the equivalence $(1) \iff (3)$ is easier to show than $(1) \iff (2)$. The reason is that being algebraic is an elementwise criterion, which is well-suited for dealing with finitely generated subfields. E.g. for $(1) \implies (3)$, as the prime subfield is always finitely generated (by $1$), it must be $\mathbb{F}_p$, and adjoining any element still gives a finitely generated subfield, which is finite and hence algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Conversely, if $K$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then a subfield $\mathbb{F}_p(a_1,..,a_n) \subseteq K$ is generated by finitely many algebraic elements, hence is a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$, and so is itself a finite field.