# A question on locally finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, algebras

I'm reading papers on the unit group of a finite dimensional algebra over locally finie field and I got stuck in locally finite field. Anyone could give me some reference books about locally finite fields?

Comment: Possibly related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633473/locally-finite-field

Answer (score 1):

A locally finite field is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Equivalently, it is any field isomorphic to a subfield of $\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

I'm not aware of books specifically about locally finite fields, but there's a section dedicated to their properties in Dixon's [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=DPHMUeM_F2kC) "Sylow Theory, Formations, and Fitting Classes in Locally Finite Groups" (Section 3.3).